# Silverlight standard loading animation does not get displayed

Tags: silverlight, loading-animation

Can anybody enlighten me as to how the standard Silverlight loading animations (the swirling blue balls) are embedded in a Silverlight application and how they work? I currently don't see it although loading the xap takes long enough for the loading animation to be displayed.

The problem is that I'm creating a xap dynamically and trying to write it to the Response Stream which might somehow interfere with the way most Silverlight applications work. So maybe there's something missing from the original aspx page or ClientBin that should be there that has been lost by accident.

I haven't found any helpful information about how the loading animation is integrated into Silverlight that could help me debug the problem so far. Does anyone know what the animation needs to triggered as expected?

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I am writing a xap file to the response stream through MVC like so... `return File(demo, "application/x-silverlight-app", "abc.xap");`  And this works, but I get no loading animation.  Like you, I have confirmed through Fiddler that the Content-Length is being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the Silverlight plugin that displays that animation - not each SL application itself. Can you post your code? Perhaps you're not specifying the content length so the plugin has no idea how big the download will be.

Comment: Agreed.  The issue is likely because you aren't writing the content length before you start sending the xap file.

Comment: The issue seems to be that although I'm writing to the output streams in chunks, this still doesn't affect the way that the xap is downloaded. I've decided to let the issue rest for the moment, since it is not high on the priority list.
The content-length is determined and flushed correctly, but that doesn't seem to help.
My basic question has been answered though, thanks. What I mostly needed to know was that the standard animation is not stored in some file that I accidentally deleted or didn't reference.